# Android: How do I make the background color of a ListView show up behind the selection?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView powered by a custom adapter that dynamically changes the background color of each row based on its contents. The getView looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        Power power = powers.get(position);
        if(row == null)
        {
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
        }

        TextView text1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

        text1.setText(power.name);
        text2.setText(power.getAttackLine());

        row.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);

        return row;
    }
```

All that works peachy, except that whenever I select an item from the list, the standard `red/orange` highlight only shows up behind the row, only visible for a few pixels on each side of it. Is there a way to get the selection to show up on top of the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in the `<ListView>` element in your layout.

Comment: Won't that just make the entire row orange, since the default ListView selector has no transparency?

Comment: I had kinda assumed he was already changing the selector. But, you are correct -- you'll need an selector nine-patch or XML-defined drawable that has appropriate transparency.

Comment: Oh, fantastic! I am currently using the default selector, but I can change it easy enough. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're using `simple_list_item_2`, which has some padding/margin built into it.  I recommend making your own version of `simple_list_item_2`, wherein you have both the height and the width set to `fill_parent`.  You can see the latest `simple_list_item_2` [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Those few pixels actually kind of saved me, because they were the only way I was able to tell that the selector was being drawn beneath the row, as opposed to not being drawn at all. You're right, though; I do need to make my own view for the rows. Thanks for your help!